# OS X & iOS Safari history.replaceState limit throws SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, browser-history

In Safari when `replaceState` [will be called more than 100 times](https://www.google.com.au/search?newwindow=1&safe=off&q=safari%20history.replaceState%20SecurityError%3A%20DOM%20Exception%2018&oq=safari%20history.replaceState%20SecurityError%3A%20DOM%20Exception%2018&gs_l=serp.3...143946.148521.0.148679.10.9.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1j2.64.serp..10.0.0.jOVAhDjjUlo), it will throw:

> SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through
>   the security policy of the user agent.

More info: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/36650

My problem is that on some specific conditions I change URL when user scrolls (using `$(window).scroll(function() {...`. As you may guess, I reach to the limit of 100 in less than 2 seconds.

`history.replaceState({}, '', newStringWithURLToUpdateInClientBrowser);`

Is there any workaround for this? Do existing libraries that allow managing `history` can solve this?

All other browsers aren't affected by this issue. Only Webkit.
Here's the fiddle to see the bug: https://jsfiddle.net/j1sxxLwy/

In Chrome it will reach to 100, but try running it in Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, if you simply catch the errors, there will be long periods where all `replaceState` calls will be ignored and your URL will stop updating altogether.

The only workaround seems to be to throttle calls to `replaceState` to occur less than every 300 milliseconds. (Chrome and Firefox appear to similarly need a 50 millisecond throttle.)

The [history-throttled](https://github.com/joliss/history-throttled) package is a drop-in replacement for `history.replaceState` and `history.pushState` that automatically applies the appropriate amount of throttling for you. (Disclosure: I'm the author.)

Answer (score 0):

have you considered throtlling the scroll event?

E.g.:

```
var timer = null;
$( window ).scroll( function() {
    clearTimeout( timer );
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
        history.replaceState( {}, '', newStringWithURLToUpdateInClientBrowser );
    }, 1000 );
} );
```

Cheers, Raoul

Comment: I think that this will just delay the calls by 1 second but not reduce the number of calls that are being made.
Delaying the calls will mean that there is a lag between the user scrolling and the UX responding to the scrolling action.