# Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Attempt to use history.pushState() more than 100 times per 30 seconds react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been using my react app for over 2 months, and all of a sudden this error pops up when I try to render a page!

```
Unhandled Rejection (SecurityError): Attempt to use history.pushState() more than 100 times per 30 seconds
```

what does this mean?!

Comment: It probably means that some of your latest changes causing a loop between two pages. Check where you call `history.pushState` and try to follow which pages are rendered.

Comment: @Gianluca It depends where is your snippet history,pushState() is written. It is an unusual observation in safari browsers

Comment: It appears you're running into the rate limiting on `pushState` imposed by Safari. Like @Eusbolh said, it's probably a bug if your app is doing that many `pushState` calls, but it's impossible to say more without looking at the code. If the rate limiting is indeed a concern, see this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419867/os-x-ios-safari-history-replacestate-limit-throws-securityerror-dom-exception) about `replaceState`. (`replaceState` and `pushState` share the same rate-limiting timer.)